# Summernote error on Meteor and Semantic-ui

Tags: javascript, jquery, meteor, semantic-ui, summernote

I used summernote package: [summernote:summernote](https://atmospherejs.com/summernote/summernote) for my website and everything work well except the feature to insert image, videos and link won't work.

Example:

- Click insert link button (image and videos are the same)
- A popup appear to set the link.
- Click anywhere on that popup, it disappeared.

Here are my code:

**post_edit.html**

```
<template name="postEdit">
<div class="ui segment">
    <form class="ui form">
        <h1 class="ui dividing header">Edit post</h1>
        <div class="field">
            <label>Title</label>
            <input type="text" id="title" name="title" value="{{title}}">
        </div>
        <label>Content</label>
        <div class="field" id="content" name="content">
            {{{content}}}
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="ui orange button"><i class="edit icon"></i> Edit</button>
        <a class="negative ui button delete"><i class="remove icon"></i> Delete</a>
        <a class="ui button" href="{{pathFor 'postPage'}}"><i class="arrow left icon"></i> Back</a>
    </form>
</div>
```

post_edit.js

```
Template.postEdit.onRendered(function(){
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#content').summernote({
        height: 400,
        maxHeight:800,
        minHeight:250,
    });
});
```

});

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this issue myself when adding autoform-summernote to my project that already uses semantic-ui. The problem is that there's a conflict between Bootstrap's and Semantic UI's $.modal() method. See these links for code references:

- [Summernote modal init](https://github.com/summernote/summernote/blob/develop/dist/summernote.js#L1929)
- [Bootstrap's modal definition](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/master/js/modal.js)
- [Semantic UI's modal definition](https://github.com/Semantic-Org/UI-Modal/blob/master/modal.js)

Summernote expects the modal method to be Bootstrap's, but instead calls Semantic UI's modal method. Because of the differences between the implementations of the modal methods, the modal closes right away when you click anywhere in the window.

Without some low-level hacks, these two packages will conflict since Semantic UI's is available globally in your project on any $('object'). If you're not using Semantic UI's modal method anywhere else in your site, you could disable it, which will fix it in this case. However, that's not a solution that works for me. Instead, I'm looking into a solution to remove summernote, or at least its dependency on Boostrap.

**Edit 1/13/2016**

I ended up replacing summernote with a different editor, https://atmospherejs.com/gildaspk/autoform-medium. It gives me the functionality I need and doesn't have conflicting dependencies.